# WPF: Binding Pictures to a grid locks them

Tags: wpf, listview, backgroundworker

I found questions with almost the same problem, but not a good answer:

I download some pictures with a backgroundworker and set them in a listview, something like this:

```
    void _backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            lsvHeros.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => lsvHeros.ItemsSource = null));
            _heros = CountersHandler.GetCounters(e.Argument.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _heros = new List<Hero>();
        }
    }
```

The Grid is defined like this:

```
            <ListView x:Name="lsvHeros" Height="140"  Width="160">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="40">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding HeroIcon}" Width="24" Height="24"  />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn  Width="110" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HeroName}" Header="" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Then I set the itemssourc in the done event:

```
    void _backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        lsvHeros.ItemsSource = _heros;
        SetWaitMode(false);
        txbHeroName.Select(0, txbHeroName.Text.Length);
        txbHeroName.Focus();
    }
```

The problem: Even if i set the itemssource to null, the pictures I downloaded are still locked.
Its definitely a problem of the binding, because when I dont bind them, I can delete them whenever I want.

Event if I want to delete the pictures in te folder manually, it tells me they are locked by another process.

So is there a proper solution to unlock the pictures so I can delete them when I rerun the program?

Thanks for your response

Müller Matthias

P.S. didnt think it matter how I download the files. I basically download the whole html text of a page, search for some patterns I know and then download. Here is the code:

```
    private static Hero HandleCounter(string str)
    {
        const string IMG = @"img src=""";
        Hero result = new Hero();

        string picture = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(IMG) + IMG.Length);
        picture = picture.Substring(0, picture.IndexOf("png", 0) + 3);


        string file = Path.Combine(FileHandler.GetFilePath(ImagePath.Counters), Path.GetFileName(picture));

        File.Create(file).Dispose();

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFile(picture, file);
        }
        result.HeroIcon = file;

        result.HeroName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).ToLower();
        result.HeroName = result.HeroName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + result.HeroName.Substring(1);

        return result;
    }
```

GetFilePath gets me a local path:

```
    public  static string GetFilePath(ImagePath iP)
    {
        string result = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Images", iP.ToString());
        if (!Directory.Exists(result))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(result);

        return result;
    }
```

Since this is just a programm I made for my pleasure, its obviously not very proper coded. I create and delete the directory to often for exmaple.

Comment: Can you show property `HeroIcon` code and how you filling it?

Comment: Also please show the logic for how you are downloading/saving the files. Are you disposing all resources properly?

Comment: I've editet the top post. As said, if I dont databind the files, it works all proper, so I guess it has to do with it.